# enriching enums - possible?

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core

I am looking for a solution to store immutable data in my code instead of the db. In the specific case I want to deal with units. Here an example for units of weight (they won't change, so its ok to store them in my code):

```
public class Unit
    {
        public Unit() { }

        public Unit(string name, string symbol, double factor, Unit baseUnit, UnitType unitType)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Symbol = symbol;
            this.Factor = factor;
            this.BaseUnit = baseUnit;
            this.UnitType = unitType;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string NamePlural { get; set; }
        public Unit BaseUnit { get; set; }
        public double Factor { get; set; }
    }



    public static class TimeUnits
    {
        public static Unit second = new Unit("second", "s", 1, null, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit microsecond = new Unit("microsecond", "μs", 0.000001, second, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit millisecond = new Unit("millisecond", "ms", 0.001, second, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit minute = new Unit("minute", "min", 60.0, second, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit hour = new Unit("hour", "h", 3600.0, second, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit day = new Unit("day", "d", 24.0, hour, UnitTypes.Time);
        public static Unit week = new Unit("week", "w", 7, day, UnitTypes.Time);
    }
```

As said I do not want to store these immutable information in the db in order to avoid additional unions for ef-core to do when retrieving data from the db.

In the case of gender I simply use an enum:

```
 public enum Gender
{
    male = 1,
    female = 2,
    not_applicable = 9,
    dont_want_to_share = 10
}
```

I would like to have a similar solution for the units. But an enum has only an Id and a Name. For things like the units shown above or other cases I need additional properties (ex. factore, unitType etc.). Thanks a lot for any hint on how I could achieve this so that ef core loads those values like it does with enums.

Comment: you may find this of interest: http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/SI.html

Comment: Just a thought:If you don't store these in your database then if at some point later another application needs to use the same database is the developer going to be able have all the information they need?

Comment: @ChrisNevill - agree, but that's the cost for better performance. My application is not intended to be that reused, but if, the documentation will help out.

Comment: Unless you're regularly selecting millions of rows at a time then I'm doubtful that the performance would be noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes is one approach, but if you want to avoid using reflection, you can implement a class that holds everything you need, something similar to this :

```
public enum UnitType
{
    Second,
    Microsecond,
    Millisecond,
    Minute,
    Hour,
    Day,
    Week
}

public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Symbol { get; private set; }

    public double Factor { get; private set; }

    public Unit Base { get; private set; }

    public Unit(UnitType unit, bool isBase = false)
    {
        Name = GetUnitName(unit);

        Symbol = GetUnitSymbol(unit);

        Factor = GetUnitFactor(unit);

        if (!isBase)
            Base = GetUnitBase(unit);
    }

    private string GetUnitName(UnitType unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case UnitType.Second:
                return "second";
            case UnitType.Microsecond:
                return "microsecond";
            case UnitType.Millisecond:
                return "millisecond";
            case UnitType.Minute:
                return "minute";
            case UnitType.Hour:
                return "hour";
            case UnitType.Day:
                return "day";
            case UnitType.Week:
                return "week";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private string GetUnitSymbol(UnitType unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case UnitType.Second:
                return "s";
            case UnitType.Microsecond:
                return "μs";
            case UnitType.Millisecond:
                return "ms";
            case UnitType.Minute:
                return "min";
            case UnitType.Hour:
                return "h";
            case UnitType.Day:
                return "d";
            case UnitType.Week:
                return "w";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private double GetUnitFactor(UnitType unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case UnitType.Second:
                return 1;
            case UnitType.Microsecond:
                return 0.000001;
            case UnitType.Millisecond:
                return 0.001;
            case UnitType.Minute:
                return 60.0;
            case UnitType.Hour:
                return 3600.0;
            case UnitType.Day:
                return 24.0;
            case UnitType.Week:
                return 7;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private Unit GetUnitBase(UnitType unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case UnitType.Microsecond:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Second, true);
            case UnitType.Millisecond:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Second, true);
            case UnitType.Minute:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Second, true);
            case UnitType.Hour:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Minute, true);
            case UnitType.Day:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Hour, true);
            case UnitType.Week:
                return new Unit(UnitType.Day, true);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


}
```

usage :

```
// initiate a new Unit instance. 
var unit = new Unit(UnitType.Week);

// Get values
var name = unit.Name;
var symbol = unit.Symbol;
var factor = unit.Factor;

// In case if some units doesn't have base
if (unit.Base != null)
{
    var baseName = unit.Base.Name;
    var baseSymbol = unit.Base.Symbol;
    var baseFactor = unit.Base.Factor;

}
```

This is just a simple example and not fully tested, it's just to show you another approach that could be implemented.

You can also use implicit operator to get the value 
Example :

```
public class Unit
{
  ......

    public static implicit operator double(Unit v) => v.Factor;

    public static implicit operator string(Unit v) => v.Symbol;

}
```

Getting the value implicitly :

```
var symbol = (string) unit; // will return the v.Symbol
var factor = (double) unit; // will return the v.Factor
```

Also, I have not showing the `UnitTypes.Time` since there is no much code about it, but I think the samples and ideas will be enough to give your thoughts the push you need.

Comment: greate idea, thanks a lot !!
I think that this is the way to go. Because of  Chris Nevill's comment above I will do some testing and see if I am overstating the problem for speed. But I'll mark this as the answer so far.

Comment: @Fabianus Chris has a point, but both ways, you can keep the database as is, and just copy the units from the database to the code, and keep the original in the database for usability for other applications.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you exatly want to do but I think attributes will be a good option. You could set attributes on every Unit Enum Fields like this one, and retrieve them by reflection any time it is needed.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class UnitTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UnitType UnitType{ get; set; }
    public UnitAttribute(UnitType unitT)
    {
        UnitType= unitT;
    }
}

    enum Unit
{
    [UnitType(UnitTypes.Time)]
    Second,

    [UnitType(UnitTypes.Time)]
    MicroSecond,

    [UnitType(UnitTypes.Time)]
    Hour
}
```

and then, when you want to retrieve it, use this method (can be made generic)

```
       public static UnitType GetUnitTypeAttribute(Unit unit)
    {
        var memberInfo = typeof(Unit).GetMember(unit.ToString());
        var result = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes<UnitTypeAttribute>(false)

        return ((UnitType)result).UnitType;
    }
```

Comment: OK, got it. I am not sure, if this is the solution because the data will be passed over to angular and I wonder if this attribute solution is usable there. In fact what I want is to avoid storing immutable data in the db because this causes queries to be more complexe and thus slower. Instead I want ef-core to load this immutable data like it does for enums from the code. See what I mean? But once loaded this data should be usable as any other class in order to be usable on the client side in angular. Anyway - thanks a lot so far for your kind support !

Comment: No, I don't quite get it, sorry. I don't know how the data is passed to angular but it's likely to require serialization somewhere. So, yes, the enum field will be serialized as a  number or a string, and all attributes will be lost if you don't reference the original project by any mean. Why don't use use const fields then?

Comment: Yes @XavierAM, that’s the problem. “Why don't use use const fields then?” - to be honest, I don’t know how. Let’s say I have an order position: 1 kg of apples. How could I store the reference to the static object “kg” in the order position so that the reference gets stored in the db and when ef-core retrieves it back from there into memory the static entity “kg” is getting related? I am not sure if you see where I am stuck.

Comment: Actually, they are plenty of ways of doing it but the MAIN problem of your issue (and this is not stated clearlyin your question) is that you want those fixed data to go cross projects/assemblies/languages. In this case, there should be a reference somewhere to the [kg] definition, it cannot fall from the sky. It should be either a DB connection, either a common package, a common DLL reference. Can you please edit your question to show where you want those data to be re-used?When you say AngularJS, is that another project or just an ASP.NET Core project with AngularJS on top of it?

Comment: Hi Xavier, I agree that this question of reference isn't clear. In my case Angular is on top of the ASP.NET Core project. Thus I'll define those classes in both environments and as I control them both it'll be fine. But never the less, I am thinking over this approach because of the comment by Chris on my question and see if this speed problem really is one. Thanks a lot for your kind input and support !